# Is there a standard enterprise technology to catalog your application web services?

Tags: web-services, uddi

Our application has thousands of web services. We are looking for a standard way / technology to provide our clients with list of web services / some documentation and some other meta information?

Comment: UDDI is a failed idea that was never widely adopted. You would do better to write up a document in your favorite word processor.

Answer (score 0):

Use UDDI and WSDL for this.

**WSDL** is the way to give "some documentation and meta data" as you have mentioned.

**UDDI** is the way to search for web services.

To get very basic introduction about both of these refer to these links on W3c school on  [WSDL & UDDI](http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_uddi.asp). Once you get a start, you can browse Internet for many UDDI providers and WSDL tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

- UDDI (its not dead)
- ebXML
- mDNS
- WS-Discovery